# window.opener.location.indexOf() function issue

Tags: javascript, indexof, window.opener

I am trying to close child window if host name are same of parent and child but its

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.opener) {
            if (window.opener.location.indexOf(document.location.hostname) != -1) {
                window.opener.location = window.location;
                window.close();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

and getting this error

```
Error: window.opener.location.indexOf is not a function
Source File: https://example.com/default
Line: 100
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The `location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) is not a string, array, or any other object which has an `indexOf` method. Perhaps you meant to use `opener.location.href.indexOf(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `location` is not a `String`, it is a `Location` object. You can use `toString` method of `location` to convert it to string:

```
window.opener.location.toString().indexOf(document.location.hostname)
```

Comment: Better to grab a specific property (like *href*) than call *toString()* though as it's more obvious which value will be used and property access is more efficient than calling a method.